# Creating cloud of cubic particles

Tags: objects, particles

So, a big part of one of my storylines is that every time a character dies, they turn into a mass of 0's and 1's and fly away. I figure I can simulate the character disappearing with a glow around the part that is dissolving, but I don't know how to create a smokelike effect with this cloud of code. Is there a way to create many specific particles that flow?

Comment: Is this BI, cycles, or BGE or something else? i mean are you trying to animate for game? or just for animation?

Comment: No no, sorry. Its going to be part of an animation, and I'm going to use code for lots of things besides a death as well. This is just Blender Internal, though I probably wouldn't mind Cycles, I need to learn it.